# android bluetooth file not transferring

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread 
{
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;     
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice; 
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream; 
    private UUID uuid =  UUID.randomUUID();
    private byte[] temp;
    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device,byte[] temp) 
    {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null; 
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        mmDevice = device; 
        this.temp = temp;       
        try 
        {
            Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
            socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        }

        catch (Exception e) { } 
        mmSocket = socket;    
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() 
    {         enter code here

        try 
        {             
            mmSocket.connect();
            write(temp);
        }
        catch (IOException connectException) 
        {
            try 
            {                 
                mmSocket.close(); 

            }
            catch (IOException closeException) 
            { }
            return;
        }

    }

    public void write(byte[] bytes) 
    {        
        try 
        {            
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            mmOutStream.flush();
            mmOutStream.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) { }    
    }

    public void cancel() 
    {
        try 
        {             
            mmSocket.close();      
        } 
        catch (IOException e) { } 
    }
}
```

I am trying to transfer a txt file to another device. I am passing the bluetooth device and message(in bytes) to this class and starting the thread form main activity. After scanning, the devices displaying and pairing is also working. I am not getting any exception in the code. But I am not receiving a file.

Why I am not receiving a file on other mobile?

Can somebody help me please.

Thanks, Faraz